# What does the “Upload photos and videos to Google Photos” checkbox mean on the Google Backup & Sync desktop app?

Tags: google-backup-and-sync

Does this option **only** upload photos and videos in the folders selected under "choose folders", or does it also upload what are in different folders? Also, does it prevent said photos and videos from being uploaded to the normal Google Drive?

[image]

**Update:**

- "Google Photos - Learn more" goes to https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103 which explains how to link Google Drive to Google Photos and vice versa.
- "Photo settings" goes to https://photos.google.com/settings, which offers one of the options mentioned in "Learn More". This option is called "Google Drive - Sync photos & videos from Google Drive". It's a yes/no question without any "which items".

Both links don't mention Backup and Sync. If you enable the options to link Google Photos and Google Drive, those options work regardless if you even have Backup and Sync or not.

Comment: Did you click the Learn More link and the Photos Settings link to learn this?

Comment: "Learn more" goes to https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103 and "Photo settings" goes to https://photos.google.com/settings - both only refer to Google Photos and not to Backup and Sync. I can tell you Drive media appears in Google Photos if you enable the relevant option there regardless if you even have Backup and Sync or not.

Comment: I don’t see the word “newly” in your screenshot.  The option your asking about applies to all applicable Photos

Comment: Google Photo is a subset of Google Drive.  Photos uploaded to Google Photo depending on the photo might or might not count against your storage quota (criteria is outside the scope of this community)

Comment: It's because I've just updated the screenshot (and now also the title). "applicable" is exactly what my question is about. I have not asked about any quota.

Comment: I did do so, but Google Photos' settings show just "Google Drive - Sync photos & videos from Google Drive - yes/no" without any "which items".

Comment: Looks like [Managing pictures with Google Backup and Sync, Photos and Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/109903) is (partially?) answering your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's finally an official answer at least to the *second* question. The answer is no, it doesn't prevent anything, and it covers both the present and the future:

> Starting in July [2019]...you’ll **still** be able to use Backup and
>   Sync on Windows or macOS to upload to **both** services.
>
> <sup>- [Google Blog](https://www.blog.google/products/photos/simplifying-google-photos-and-google-drive/)</sup>

Which links to this FAQ that explains it even more specifically:

> Check if you turned on **Upload newly added photos and videos to Google Photos**.
>
> If you use Backup & Sync to upload photos and videos to Drive and Photos, it will upload a copy to **each** service.
>
> <sup>- [Google Support](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9316089)</sup>